are letters of recommendation always required for lecturer and/or postdoc positions in the CS field in the USA?
I want to know whether letters of recommendations are always a requirement for all lecturer/postdoc positions (across all universities) in the USA in the computer science field?
If not are there any universities that don't require these letters? if not, how to apply for such positions without the need for recommendations?

This sounds like an XY problem.

Pretty much any job in the US in ‘academia’ will require references. My lab does not require formal letters of reference, but I am required to call the provided references and ask certain questions. If you are unwilling or unable to provide references to contact you won’t be hired. Simple as that.

that's also a proof of your inability to make fair competency judgement without (a possible rigged) opinion from others.

@Sam - after hiring dozens of people over the years, I can look back now and say that my judgements were pretty darn good. Almost universally without needing to contact the references, but fighting against or lying to HR is just not a battle worth waging. But, if nobody wants to speak up on your behalf, well, there are some issues there that I'm not willing to take on in an employee. Good luck.

I don't think there is any rule that applies to "every university" in the US. Not many anyway. But not requiring letters would be very rare. Very rare.
Most universities are bound by advertising rules for most positions other than "per-course adjunct lecturers". Those are probably available, but have no benefits (usually) and no guarantee of permanence. (Some are unionized, however, so a bit better.) But regular, even not on the tenure track  and postdoc positions are usually advertised and there are usually lots of applicants, leading to the problem of choosing the "best" candidate for the position. Letters of recommendation are one of the best predictors of success when they come from someone who can be trusted and who has nothing to gain from a good letter.
One possible path to a regular position, though not a post doc, would be to serve as an adjunct for a while, underpaid and under-appreciated. If you do a good job and make yourself known to the faculty over a few years, then letters might not be required, though you would still probably need to compete for a regular position due to the rules. Some of those rules at some places are enshrined in law in the US.

Even the private universities?

I can't find US regulations that require it, but the universities that come up in searching suggest that they make faculty searches as wide as possible. That is, they have their own regulations at least. If nothing else, this helps them show non-discrimination and also give a rich field of candidates. And universities that receive federal funds in various ways are more likely to be bound by regulation. There are probably exceptions among those that don't accept any federal funding, but one questions their reputation.

All universities in the US I've ever heard of use this system. If there are some that don't, they will likely have other ways of ascertaining a candidate's qualifications, and that other system will also rely on people who actually know you.
In other words, there is in all likelihood no way for you to avoid the scrutiny. Of course, the obvious question is why you don't want to subject yourself to the system as it is? Do you have something to hide? Or are you just on a quest to demonstrate that the existing system is stupid, at the risk of self-immolation?

Even the private universities?

They operate in much the same way. But like I said, even if they don't require letters per se, they still will want to have references they can contact to ask about you. What I don't understand is why that bothers you.
